# echo command not found while testing selenium with phpunit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I am getting an **ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo'** executing a selenium script with phpunit. Based on the output that echo command should be included in my version of PHPUnit. The selenium script does execute successfully in the firefox selenium IDE.

```
mkdir_build:

phpunit:
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] .
     [exec]  TestFull
     [exec]  E
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time: 11 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb
     [exec] 
     [exec] There was 1 error:
     [exec] 
     [exec] 1) TestFull::testNumberOne
     [exec] PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Response from Selenium RC server for testComplete().
     [exec] ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo'.
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] /directory/to/tests/TestFull.php:14
     [exec] 
     [exec] FAILURES!
     [exec] Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

And the RC server output:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server.jar -port 4445 -debug
13:23:08.426 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 14.2-b01
13:23:08.428 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.28-15-server i386
13:23:08.439 INFO - v2.0 [a2], with Core v2.0 [a2]
13:23:08.439 INFO - Selenium server running in debug mode.

13:25:05.661 DEBUG - ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_93352
13:25:05.662 DEBUG - Browser 2c8b3b5657a640db9fb278ecbd01049e/:top sel_93352 posted ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo'
13:25:05.662 DEBUG - ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_93352
13:25:05.662 DEBUG - putting command: ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo'
13:25:05.662 DEBUG - ..command put?: true
13:25:05.662 DEBUG -    sel_93352 commandHolder sel_93352 getCommand() called
13:25:05.662 DEBUG - waiting for data for at most 10 more s
13:25:05.662 DEBUG - data from polling: ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo'
13:25:05.662 DEBUG -    sel_93352 commandResultHolder sel_93352 getResult() -> ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo'
13:25:05.663 DEBUG - Got result: ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo' on session 2c8b3b5657a640db9fb278ecbd01049e
13:25:05.663 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Unknown command: 'echo' on session 2c8b3b5657a640db9fb278ecbd01049e
13:25:05.663 DEBUG - Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
13:25:05.663 DEBUG - RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Apr 2010 20:25:05 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Linux/2.6.28-15-server i386 java/1.6.0_16
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium IDE `echo` command is not supported in Selenium RC, instead you should use your client language to echo out to file/console. For example, the following should print to console in PHP:

```
print("Print this!" . "\n");
```